# How To Persist Parameters Through Different Rails Controllers Actions In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

What should one use to persist instance variables through different controller#actions, without using the session?

Here is an example of the problem:

There is an **Hospitalization** which **has_one** **Prescription**

From hospitalization#show I have a link_to prescription#new with additional parameters as seen bellow:

```
<%= link_to t('hospitalizations.prescription'), new_prescription_path(hospitalization_id: @hospitalization.id,...)
```

And the trick is: at prescription#new I can retrieve

```
@hospitalization = Hospitalization.find_by(id: params[:hospitalization_id])
```

But when I press submit and it comes to prescription#create, **@hospitalization** answers to **nil** when trying to do something like

```
@prescription = @hospitalization.build_prescription(prescription_params)
```

How would be the best way to instantiate these parameters so they persist or get easily carried between the controller#actions one needs? How should I instantiate the belonging model Prescription? Should I put the ID directly there, on prescription#new? Like:

```
@prescription = Prescription.new(hospitalization_id: params[:hospitalization_id])
```

Comment: so I'm understanding you - you want a new prescription (an empty one?) created with every new Hospitalization?

Comment: Yes, every hospitalization should have its own prescription, but they are not meant to be registered together. They're separate stages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [neseted resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) this way:

```
resources hospitalizations do
  resource :prescription
end
```

This way your path is going to look like this:

```
/hospitalizations/:hospitalization_id/prescription
```

and you can use the following to generate it:

```
new_hospitalization_prescription_path(@hospitalization)
```

now in your controller you can access the parameter as `params[:hospitalization_id]`. For example in the `create` method of your `PrescriptionController`:

```
def create
  hospitalization = Hospitalization.find(params[:hospitalization])
  prescription = Prescription.new(hospitalization: hospitalization, ...)
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Tried your solution, and I found that I had to add `:url => new_hospitalization_prescription_path` to my `form_for @prescription`
Should that be all? Because now I'm getting a **No route matches [POST] "/hospitalizations/6/prescriptions/new"** which is weird because the route is in my rake routes output.

Comment: Did you restart your server?

Comment: Yes, I did, and just realized the form_for was for prescription#new, while it should be for prescription#create, silly mistake here. Altho I still cannot create, it gives me the same error "undefined method ... for nil:nilClass" referring to @hospitalization. Should I change anything else there?

Comment: How are you initializing `@hospitalization`? Checkout your params and confirm that `:hospitalization_id` is present. Remember that `@hospitalization` is not automagically passed between controller methods.

Comment: Tried something like `@hospitalization = Hospitalization.find(params[:hospitalization])

@prescription = Prescription.new(prescription_params)` but getting 'couldn't find Hospitalization without an id' this is the part that tricks me everytime.

Comment: you should have `params[:hospitalization_id]` and not `params[:hospitalization]`. If you check `bundle exec rails routes | grep hospitalization` you will see something like `/hospitalization/:hospitalization_id/prescriptions` and you know exactly what the placeholder in `params` is called (e.g. `hospitalization_id`)

Comment: Yes, corrected that already and also added `@prescription.hospitalization_id = @hospitalization.id` below Prescription.new(params), and it worked like a charm! Now I'm only having trouble on how to access the show action for the created prescription.

Comment: Same thing! Take a look at your `rake routes` and find out the path name and just as `new` path but here you have to pass both `hospitalization` **and** `prescription` as arguments.

Comment: It returns me **No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"prescriptions", :format=>nil, :hospitalization_id=>#<Prescription id: 13, created_at: "2015-02-06 13:46:36", updated_at: "2015-02-06 13:46:36", hospitalization_id: 6>, :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]** no matter what I try I can't seem to get this ID there, and don't even know why is it for, as I already have hospitalization_id and prescription_id.

Comment: Oh got it! What a headache a comma can give us haha Thanks for the help! I think I've got to understand how nested resources work now, will solve many problems.
P.s.: If you want to update something in your answer you might find useful from these comments, I'll be accepting it soon.

Comment: You could also do me a favor and mark the answer as the correct answer.

Comment: Just did, just gave you sometime to edit it if you want, I don't know if you can edit it after I accept a final answer, and then went out to lunch. :p Thanks again for the help! You showed me some really useful knowledge.

Comment: I think I can edit but have never tried! So glad that I could help and really appreciate your comment :)